# Stream compare two lists and simultaneously modify one

Tags: java, java-stream

Custom class

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Product {
    private String name;
    private String systemId;
    private String productId;
    private String productPartId;
    private boolean isMandatory;
    private String status;

    public Product(String name, String systemId, String productId, String productPartId) {
        this.name = name;
        this.systemId = systemId;
        this.productId = productId;
        this.productPartId = productPartId;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Product product = (Product) o;
        return Objects.equals(systemId, product.systemId) && Objects.equals(productId, product.productId)
                && Objects.equals(productPartId, product.productPartId);
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(systemId, productId, productPartId);
    }
}
```

Two lists containing the above custom object:

```
List<Product>bankConceptProducts = //has isMandatory and status set but NOT name.
List<Product>customerProducts = //has name set but NOT isMandatory, status.
```

Both the above lists have the fields used in equals() and hashCode() set properly.

Now, I am trying to create an 'intersection' list and it is working as expected:

```
customerProducts.stream().filter(bankConceptProducts::contains).toList()
```

but I wish to modify the bankConceptProducts(so NOT the source list) list b**y setting the name during the filter step**(to avoid reiteration just to set the name). Is it possible or do I have to use map(this means one more iteration) or something after toList() ?

Note that name is not part of the equals() and hashCode(), hence, I believe it must not cause any data/comparison inconsistency.

Update:
I am aware that this can be achieved with forEach, I just wanted to establish if can be done using Stream API as well.

The forEach does what I am trying to achieve:

```
Map<Product, Product>bankConceptProducts = bankConceptsByProductId.get(customerConcept.getProductId()).
                        getProducts().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), Function.identity()));

                List<Product>customerConceptProducts = new ArrayList<>();

                customerProducts.forEach(customerProduct -> {

                    Optional<Product> customerConceptProduct = Optional.ofNullable
                            (bankConceptProducts.get(customerProduct));

                    if(customerConceptProduct.isPresent()){
                        customerConceptProduct.get().setName(customerProduct.getName());
                        customerConceptProducts.add(customerConceptProduct.get());
                    }
                });
```

Comment: 1) why do you want to 'avoid reiteration' ? 2) afaik, if you want to modify just the bankConceptProducts you have to clone Product object, or else you modify the source object too !

Comment: @StefanoRiffaldi I didn't understand both 1. and 2. As far as 2. is concerned, why to clone? I tested it with the old forEach approach, and it works well.

Comment: 1) You want to set the name only for the objects in `bankConceptProducts`, which matched the filter, with the name of the element from `customerProducts`, correct? 2) Can the list contain duplicates?

Comment: You say you want to avoid reiteration, but in fact you are already reiterating `bankConceptProducts` many times! Every time you do `filter(bankConceptProducts::contains)`, the `filter` method iterates through `bankConceptProducts`.

Comment: @Chaosfire 1. Correct 2. No duplicates in either list.

Comment: @k314159 Yeah, I am aware of the iterations filter(bankConceptProducts::contains) but do I need one more set of iterations to simply set the name?

Comment: How big is `bankConceptProducts`? If it contains more than a couple of dozen elements, you might want to put them in a `Map`, otherwise the iterations each time would make the performance suffer.

Comment: @k314159 I agree. The bankConceptProducts can vary(depending on the input params by the user), and might have anywhere from 10 to 50 entries.
If you check the comment in the forEach code, I was already thinking of creating a Map but it sounded a bit dirty/lame.
I tested with the Map, it works well. Updated the forEach part to explain better.

Answer (score 1):

To modify the bankConceptProducts list during the filtering step without causing reiteration, you can use the forEach method instead of toList. This allows you to modify the elements of the bankConceptProducts list while streaming over customerProducts.

This code iterates over customerProducts, filters them based on whether they are contained in bankConceptProducts, and then iterates over each matching product in bankConceptProducts. If a corresponding product is found, it sets the name from customerProduct.

```
customerProducts.stream()
            .filter(bankConceptProducts::contains)
            .forEach(customerProduct -> {
                // Find the corresponding product in bankConceptProducts
                Product bankProduct = bankConceptProducts.stream()
                        .filter(product -> product.equals(customerProduct))
                        .findFirst()
                        .orElse(null);

                // Set the name if the corresponding product exists in bankConceptProducts
                if (bankProduct != null) {
                    bankProduct.setName(customerProduct.getName());
                }
            });
```

Comment: Yeah, I am aware of that. What I want to establish is can this be done using Streams API. I updated my answer to make the question clearer.

Answer (score 1):

This is doable, but you need to manually check for the matching element and then mumate it.

```
private static boolean setNameToMatch(Product customerProduct, List<Product> bankConceptProducts) {
  for (Product bankConceptProduct : bankConceptProducts) {
    if (bankConceptProduct.equals(customerProduct)) {
      bankConceptProduct.setName(customerProduct.getName());
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

And use method above for the filter:

```
List<Product> result = customerProducts.stream()
        .filter(cp -> setNameToMatch(cp, bankConceptProducts))
        .toList();
```

But this filter does more than filtering and iterating the list to find the match is O(N), `List.contains()` as well. I would use a `Map` and simple loop instead of stream:

```
Map<ProductKey, Product> bankMap = bankConceptProducts
  .stream()
  .collect(Collectors.toMap(ProductKey::fromProduct, Function.identity()));
  //this mapping depends on no duplicates in the list
  //if there are duplicates you need conflict resolution
List<Product> result = new ArrayList<>();
for (Product customerProduct : customerProducts) {
  Product matchingBankProduct = bankMap.get(ProductKey.fromProduct(customerProduct));
  if (matchingBankProduct != null) {
    matchingBankProduct.setName(customerProduct.getName());
    result.add(customerProduct);
  }
}
System.out.println(result);
```

ProductKey, but you can use `Product` directly instead, since hashCode and equals are overridden:

```
public record ProductKey(String systemId, String productId, String productPartId) {

  public static ProductKey fromProduct(Product product) {
    return new ProductKey(product.getSystemId(), product.getProductId(), product.getProductPartId());
  }
}
```

Comment: I agree. I also used a Map in the end(check the forEach part of my question) . I just wanted to figure out if Streams can do it(my knowledge of Streaming API is too less to establish) efficiently and concisely than the good-old forEach.

Comment: You can combine the map with the stream approach (the method will use `Map` instead of `List`), but my main concern is that the filter does 2 things - filtering and mutating.

Comment: Exactly my thoughts! So I have decided to not mix filtering and mutating, and will stick to the forEach solution, even if it seems a bit hacky.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest an alternate solution which does not use streams and iterates each list once only.

- Sort each list and then iterate through both lists at the same time.
- If the current element of both lists is equal, create a new `Product` instance with relevant data extracted from the current elements and add it to a third list which holds your required result.
- If the element of one list is less than the element of the other list, get the next value from the list with the lower element.
- Once you have exhausted one list, continue iterating through the other list until you have exhausted that one too.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public record Product(String name,
                      String systemId,
                      String productId,
                      String productPartId,
                      boolean isMandatory,
                      String status) implements Comparable<Product> {

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Product o) {
        int result;
        if (o == null) {
            result = 1;
        }
        else {
            result = compareStrings(systemId, o.systemId());
            if (result == 0) {
                result = compareStrings(productId, o.productId());
                if (result == 0) {
                    result = compareStrings(productPartId, o.productPartId);
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        boolean equal = this == o;
        if (!equal) {
            if (o != null) {
                if (getClass().equals(o.getClass())) {
                    Product product = (Product) o;
                    equal = Objects.equals(systemId, product.systemId)   &&
                            Objects.equals(productId, product.productId) &&
                            Objects.equals(productPartId, product.productPartId);
                }
            }
        }
        return equal;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(systemId, productId, productPartId);
    }

    private int compareStrings(String me, String it) {
        int result;
        if (me == null) {
            if (it == null) {
                result = 0;
            }
            else {
                result = -1;
            }
        }
        else {
            if (it == null) {
                result = 1;
            }
            else {
                result = me.compareTo(it);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //has isMandatory and status set but NOT name
        Set<Product> bankConceptProducts = new TreeSet<Product>();
        bankConceptProducts.add(new Product(null, "System ID 1", "Product ID 1", "Product Part ID 1", true, "Status 1"));
        bankConceptProducts.add(new Product(null, "System ID 2", "Product ID 2", "Product Part ID 2", true, "Status 2"));
        bankConceptProducts.add(new Product(null, "System ID 3", "Product ID 3", "Product Part ID 3", true, "Status 3"));
        bankConceptProducts.add(new Product(null, "System ID 4", "Product ID 4", "Product Part ID 4", true, "Status 4"));
        bankConceptProducts.add(new Product(null, "System ID 5", "Product ID 5", "Product Part ID 5", true, "Status 5"));

        //has name set but NOT isMandatory, status.
        Set<Product> customerProducts = new TreeSet<Product>();
        customerProducts.add(new Product("Name A", "System ID A", "Product ID A", "Product Part ID A", false, null));
        customerProducts.add(new Product("Name 2", "System ID 2", "Product ID 2", "Product Part ID 2", false, null));
        customerProducts.add(new Product("Name C", "System ID C", "Product ID C", "Product Part ID C", false, null));
        customerProducts.add(new Product("Name 4", "System ID 4", "Product ID 4", "Product Part ID 4", false, null));
        Iterator<Product> bankIter = bankConceptProducts.iterator();
        Iterator<Product> custIter = customerProducts.iterator();
        Product bank = null;
        if (bankIter.hasNext()) {
            bank = bankIter.next();
        }
        Product cust = null;
        if (custIter.hasNext()) {
            cust = custIter.next();
        }
        List<Product> result = new ArrayList<>();
        if (bank != null  &&  cust != null) {
            while (true) {
                int val = bank.compareTo(cust);
                if (val == 0) {
                    result.add(new Product(cust.name(),
                                           bank.systemId(),
                                           bank.productId(),
                                           bank.productPartId(),
                                           bank.isMandatory(),
                                           bank.status()));
                    if (bankIter.hasNext()) {
                        bank = bankIter.next();
                    }
                    else {
                        break;
                    }
                    if (custIter.hasNext()) {
                        cust = custIter.next();
                    }
                    else {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else if (val > 0) {
                    if (custIter.hasNext()) {
                        cust = custIter.next();
                    }
                    else {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if (bankIter.hasNext()) {
                        bank = bankIter.next();
                    }
                    else {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            while (bankIter.hasNext()) {
                bank = bankIter.next();
                int val = bank.compareTo(cust);
                if (val == 0) {
                    result.add(new Product(cust.name(),
                                           bank.systemId(),
                                           bank.productId(),
                                           bank.productPartId(),
                                           bank.isMandatory(),
                                           bank.status()));
                    break;
                }
            }
            while (custIter.hasNext()) {
                cust = custIter.next();
                int val = cust.compareTo(bank);
                if (val == 0) {
                    result.add(new Product(cust.name(),
                                           bank.systemId(),
                                           bank.productId(),
                                           bank.productPartId(),
                                           bank.isMandatory(),
                                           bank.status()));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        result.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Output when running the above code is:

```
Product[name=Name 2, systemId=System ID 2, productId=Product ID 2, productPartId=Product Part ID 2, isMandatory=true, status=Status 2]
Product[name=Name 4, systemId=System ID 4, productId=Product ID 4, productPartId=Product Part ID 4, isMandatory=true, status=Status 4]
```

- Java [records](https://openjdk.org/jeps/395) were finalized in JDK 16.
- The sets are ordered first by `systemId`, then by `productId` and finally by `productPartId` as I believe this mirrors your `equals` method (in class `Product`).
- In the above code I use a `TreeSet` – rather than a `List` – since you stated that there were no duplicates and a `TreeSet` automatically sorts its added elements which makes sorting simpler. If you require `List`, then there are ways to sort a `List` which I believe you can discover for yourself.